# What does ampersand mean here?

Tags: c++, c++11

The & below looks to be a new feature (c++ 11?) instead of just extracting the address of a variable, since put it (&) in different position makes the value t different. What does it mean?

```
// test_ampersand.cpp
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv [])
{
    int a[10] = { 2, };
    int* p = a;

    int t = (int) *((short *&) p);
    // int t = (int) *((short *) &p);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: No, this is not a new feature. Technically, it isn't a C++ feature at all, since C++ attributes no behaviour to this code.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes, do you mean this is invalid C++ code?

Comment: I mean that C++ doesn't define what it does, so it can hardly be called a C++ feature.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes Are you sure? As per `[expr.reinterpret.cast]p11`: "An lvalue expression of type `T1` can be cast to the type “reference to `T2`” if an expression of type “pointer to `T1`” can be explicitly converted to the type “pointer to `T2`” using a `reinterpret_cast`." And you can certainly `reinterpret_cast` from `int**` to `short**`.

Comment: Can you read an `int` object using a pointer to `short`?

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes Good question, seeing as they're both standard-layout etc.; the answer's probably "no". But I see your point now. The whole `*((short*&)p)` construct is most likely UB. But just the `(short*&)` cast is not, and I understood that to be the bit the OP was asking about.

Comment: It depends what you mean by "new". I believe references were a fairly late addition to the language; but they've been there for two or three decades now.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes: never mind accessing the `int`, you can't even access an `int*` object using a `short*` lvalue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not a new feature, it's simply a reference - and it's casting `p` to a reference to `short*`. In other words, you're telling the compiler: "think the bytes comprising `p` are of type `short*`." (It also means you could assign to them like that, but that doesn't apply here).

The difference between a cast from `int*` to `short*` and one to `short* &` depends on the processor architecture. In case `int*` and `short*` have the same representation in memory, there is no difference. It will simply change what dereferencing the pointer gives you.

However, if you were on a (perhaps hypothetical) platform where a `short` is smaller than an `int` and at the same time an `int` is the smallest normally addressable unit, it would actually be quite different. The reason is that in such case, a `short*` would have to store an address (of an `int`) *and also* and offset of the `short` within that `int`. So it would be the case that `sizeof(int*) < sizeof(short*)`. Note that there are actual architectures where `sizeof(int*) < sizeof(char*)` for precisely this reason, so it's not *so* far-fetched.

On such architecture, a cast `int* -> short*` would mean "compute a representation of `short*` such that it points to the same location as the original `int*`." A cast `int* -> short*&` would mean "interpret the representation of `int*` as a `short*`." That might even be invalid code, if `sizeof(int*) < sizeof(short*)` on such a platform.

Answer (score 2):

`short *&` is a reference to a pointer to `short`. This is plain C++. It's not really needed there anyway, because the result is never used as an lvalue - the pointer just gets dereferenced as an rvalue right away.